# How can I see that a parametric surface is "pointy"?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

I have the function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$
\phi(u,v) = (u^2,u^3,v)
$$
which looks like
[[image: Plot of function <span class=]$\phi$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOhNu.png)

I need to prove that the points on the line $\{ (0,0,z) | z\in \mathbb{R} \}$ are "pointy" and therefore $\phi$ isn't a valid homeomorphism that can be used to define a chart of a differentiable manifold. I thought I might be able to show that we cannot define a tangent surface at the points located on this line, but I'm not quite sure how to formalize this idea.

Any help on how to proceed would be truly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to construct tangent vectors to the surface $x=u^2$, $y=u^3$, $z=v$, they are the vectors $\partial_u(x,y,z)=(2u,3u^2,0)$ and $\partial_v(x,y,z)=(0,0,1)$. When $u=0$ the first is the zero vector so at those points this pair cannot span a tangent plane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This surface can also be written as $f^{-1}(0)$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ is the map $f(x,y,z)=x^3-y^2$. The surface is 'pointy' because the partial derivatives of $f$ vanish along the line $x=y=0$. The technical term is *singular*.

Your $\phi$ is not a homeomorphism, but remember what this means. A homeomorphism is continuous with continuous inverse. This function does not have any inverse as it is not *surjective*. The failure of $\phi$ to be a homeomorphism is not because of the singularity!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if we defined $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \phi(\mathbb{R}^2)$ so that $\phi$ is surjective? In this case, would $\phi$ be a homeomorphism?

Comment: Define $\psi:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$, $\psi:(x,y,z)\mapsto (\sqrt[3]{y},z)$. This map restricted to the surface provides a continuous inverse to $\phi$. $\phi$ is also continuous, so, yes in this sense $\phi$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: You asked about smooth manifolds: my map $\psi$ is not smooth, so while the surface is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ via $\phi$, it is not diffeomorphic to it via $\phi$.

Comment: If you like the answer, you can accept it :)

Comment: The same argument appears to apply to the mapping $f(x, y, z) = x^3-y^3$, whose partials vanish along the $z$-axis but whose zero set is the (smooth) plane $x=y$. That is, the stated vanishing of partials does not imply the level set itself is non-manifold.

Comment: If your surface is defined by a polynomial, vanishing derivatives are not sufficient for a singularity: we need also that the polynomial be *irreducible*. Your polynomial is not irreducible as $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$.